# Magento 2: Create Dropdown InstallData Attribute Programmaticaly

Tags: magento2.2

I want to create InstallData & UpgradeData for attribute product and automatic added to All AttributeSet.

I've created the dropdown attribute product like this below.

[image: Attribute]

Answer (score 1):

If it is a new module and you didn't run it before, use `InstallData` otherwise you use `UpgradeData`

Assuming that you already have run your module:

> app/code/{Vendor}/{Modulename}/Setup/UpgradeData.php

```
<?php

namespace {Vendor}\{Modulename}\Setup;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetup;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class UpgradeData implements  UpgradeDataInterface
{
    private $customerSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
    }
    public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context){
        $setup->startSetup();

        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.1', '<')) {

            $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
            $customerSetup->addAttribute(
                Customer::ENTITY,
                'product_type',
                [
                    'type' => 'int',
                    'label' => 'Product Type',
                    'input' => 'select',
                    'source' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Table',
                    'required' => true,
                    'default' => '0',
                    'sort_order' => 160,
                    'system' => false,
                    'position' => 160,
                    'option' =>
                        array (
                            'values' =>
                                array (
                                    0 => 'Option1',
                                    1 => 'Option2',
                                    2 => 'Option3',
                                ),
                        ),
                ]
            );
            $myAttribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'product_type');

            $myAttribute->setData(
                'used_in_forms', ['adminhtml_checkout','adminhtml_customer','adminhtml_customer_address','customer_account_edit','customer_address_edit','customer_register_address']);
            $myAttribute->save();

        }

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create file **InstallData.php** app/code/ModuleNameSpace/YourModuleName/Setup

```
       <?php
    namespace ModuleNameSpace\ModuleName\Setup;

    use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
    use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

    class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
    {
        private $eavSetupFactory;

        public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
        {
            $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        }

        public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
        {
            $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
               $eavSetup->addAttribute(
                       \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
                   'international',
                   [
                       'group' => 'General',
                       'type' => 'int',
                       'label' => 'Product Type',
                       'backend' => '',
                       'input' => 'select',
                       'wysiwyg_enabled'   => false,
                       'source' => 'Namespace\ModuleName\Model\Config\Source\ProductType',
                       'required' => true,
                       'sort_order' => 15,
                       'global' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                       'used_in_product_listing' => false,
                       'visible_on_front' => false,
               ]
           );

           $setup->endSetup();
        }
?>
```

2. Create file **ProductType.php**  app/code/ModuleNameSpace/ModuleName/Model/Config/Source

```
<?php

namespace ModuleNameSpace\ModuleName\Model\Config\Source;

use Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\OptionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;

/**
 * Custom Attribute Renderer
 *
 * @author      Webkul Core Team <support@webkul.com>
 */
class Options extends \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\AbstractSource
{
    /**
     * @var OptionFactory
     */
    protected $optionFactory;

    /**
     * @param OptionFactory $optionFactory
     */
    /*public function __construct(OptionFactory $optionFactory)
    {
        $this->optionFactory = $optionFactory;  
        //you can use this if you want to prepare options dynamically  
    }*/

    /**
     * Get all options
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAllOptions()
    {
        /* your Attribute options list*/
        $this->_options=[ ['label'=>'Select Options', 'value'=>''],
                          ['label'=>'Option1', 'value'=>'1']
                          ['label'=>'Option2', 'value'=>'2']
                          ['label'=>'Option3', 'value'=>'3']
                         ];
        return $this->_options;
    }

    /**
     * Get a text for option value
     *
     * @param string|integer $value
     * @return string|bool
     */
    public function getOptionText($value)
    {
        foreach ($this->getAllOptions() as $option) {
            if ($option['value'] == $value) {
                return $option['label'];
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Add bellow installation script in your module at path app/code/{Namespace} /{Module-Name}/Setup/InstallData.php

```
<?php
namespace {Namespace}\{Module-name}\Setup;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set as AttributeSet;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

/**
 * @var CustomerSetupFactory
 */
protected $customerSetupFactory;

/**
 * @var AttributeSetFactory
 */
private $attributeSetFactory;

/**
 * @param CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
 * @param AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
 */
public function __construct(
    CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
    AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
) {
    $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
    $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
}


/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{

    /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
    $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

    $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
    $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

    /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
    $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
    $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

    $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'customer_type', [

        'type'          => 'static',
        'label'         => 'Customer Type',
        'input'         => 'select',
        'source'        => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Table',
        'required'      => false,
        'sort_order'    => 210,
        'visible'       => false,
        'system'        => false,
        'validate_rules'=> 'a:0:{}',
        'position'      => 210,
        'admin_checkout' => 1,
        'option'         => ['values' => ['Buyer', 'Seller']],
    ]);

    $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'customer_type')
    ->addData([
        'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
        'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
        'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer'],
    ]);

    $attribute->save();


}
}
```